# Why is Scala Join Timing Out?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join a table to itself. I am getting rows of a table, then, on a second request, getting rows again (so they may or may not be the same rows) and limiting each of them to 10 rows each. I can show each of the result sets, but when I join them, Scala just hangs and then times out. What could be the issue?

```
override def joinMe(): Unit = {
val conf: Config = ConfigFactory.load()

val options = SparkOptions.createOptions(conf.getString("dashDb.driver"),
  conf.getString("dashDb.url"),
  conf.getString("dashDb.username"),
  conf.getString("dashDb.password"),
  "1000",
  conf.getString("dashDb.dbTable")
)
val sourceDF = JdbcRepository.read(options).limit(10)

sourceDF.show()

val targetDF = sourceDF

targetDF.show()

sourceDF.join(
  targetDF,
  sourceDF("EMPLOYEE_CNUM_ID") === targetDF("EMPLOYEE_CNUM_ID")
).show(10)
}
```

but I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]
```

**Thanks for your time!**

Comment: MY first guess would be that there is really a connection issue that is just exhibiting as a timeout. Can you check whether the server is receiving the db call?

Comment: Hi @JustinPihony, the `sourceDF.show()` and `targetDF.show()` are both printing our the same 10 rows

Comment: What is the DAG shown as, or even the generated SQL? It should push the limit down and it should be a join of 2 ten row datasets, but maybe something is causing it to join the entire table, which could be slow enough to timeout.

Comment: Does the limit not apply until after the join? Because I dont see why the join takes so long

Comment: Catalyst should push these down to the db layer, so I wouldn't expect - but you should be able to visualize these from the Spark UI - the DAG and executed SQL should be listed